# Nesting lambda expression with passing parameter by reference in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, pass-by-reference

I am trying to use lambda expressions in C++. A example of lambda expression is demonstrated below. The input parameter of function f1 is a std::unique_ptr and the output parameter is also a std::unique_ptr.

```cpp
    auto f1 = [](std::unique_ptr<float[]> &input_data, int size)->std::unique_ptr<float[]>
    {
        auto return_data = std::make_unique<float[]>(size);
        for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size; loop_number++)
        {
            return_data[loop_number] = input_data[loop_number] + 1;                  //  for example
        }
        return return_data;
    };
```

The non-nesting usage of function f1 is shown as below. It runs successfully.

```cpp
    int size_for_testing = 100;
    auto test_object = std::make_unique<float[]>(size_for_testing);
    auto result = f1(test_object, size_for_testing);
    for (int loop_number = 0; loop_number < size_for_testing; loop_number++)
    {
        std::cout << result[loop_number] << std::endl;
    }
```

When it comes to the nesting case as shown as below, there is an error appeared.

```cpp
auto result = f1(f1(test_object, size_for_testing), size_for_testing);
```

The compiler shows C2664 error with `'std::unique_ptr<float [],std::default_delete<float []>> main::<lambda_1>::operator ()(std::unique_ptr<float [],std::default_delete<float []>> &,int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<float [],std::default_delete<float []>>' to 'std::unique_ptr<float [],std::default_delete<float []>> &'` error message.

The `result` above should be as same as below.

```cpp
    auto result1 = f1(test_object, size_for_testing);
    auto result = f1(result1, size_for_testing);
```

I am wondering that 1) Is it inappropriate to write lambda expression with passing parameters by reference? 2) Why the non-nesting usage of function f1 is fine but the error C2664 appears in the nesting usage?

OS: Windows 10 1909

IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.4.5

Comment: It would improve the question to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code attempts to bind an lvalue reference (1st arg of the outer `f1`) to a prvalue (return value of the inner `f1`), this is not allowed.

You could fix it by passing by const reference, `std::unique_ptr<float[]> const &input_data` .

I would consider having the parameter be `float const *` since the function's operation does not depend on how memory management worked for the input array. In fact `std::span` would be appropriate here too.

Comment: Using a bare pointer would also produce an error when nesting

Comment: @AlanBirtles: change usage appropriately too: `f1(f1(test_object.get(), size_for_testing).get(), size_for_testing)`.

Comment: In addition to @M.M, the array is not modified, so he has chosen `float const *` rather than `float*`